# php loop - check if on last multiple before total number

Tags: php, foreach

Let's say that you have an array of 30 characters and you are looping through them to build a visual grid in HTML. I want to know when it's on the last row of items and apply a CSS rule. For every 8th item, I can use the code below to apply an additional CSS rule:

```
$cnt=1;
foreach ($characters as $index => $character){
   if ($cnt % 8==0) echo "newline";
   $cnt++;
}
```

Since I only have 30 characters, there will be 3 lines with a shorter 4th line (it will only have 6 items). How can I flag every character from 24-30 as belonging to the last row. The total number of characters will always vary.

Comment: what do you mean by `flag every character from 24-30` ..  can you also add expected results ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rowCount = 8; // the number of items per row
$lastRowStarts = intval(floor(count($characters) / $rowCount)) * $rowCount;
// e.g: floor(30 / 8) * 8 = 3 * 8 = 24 = <index of first item in last row>

$index = 1;
foreach ($characters as $character) {
   if ($index >= $lastRowStarts) echo "last line";

   $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cnt=1;
$length = strlen($characters);//if a string
//$length = count($characters);//if an array
foreach ($characters as $index => $character){
   if ($cnt % 8==0) echo "newline";
   if($index > ($length - 8))//or whatever number you want
   {
      echo 'flagged';//flag here however
   }
   $cnt++;
}
```

Comment: So $cnt value never changes. :P

Comment: @trickyzter whoops.  I just copy and pasted the function at the top.  I must have overwritten the $cnt++;  nice catch ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any size of characters as long as your row length is 8. This assumes `$cnt` is a variable that keeps a loop counter.

```
$count = count($charchters)

foreach ($characters as $index => $character){
   if ($cnt % 8==0) echo "newline";
   if ($cnt < $count && $cnt > ($count - $count % 8)) echo "This is on the last row";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_pop` to get the last row after groping them with `array_chunk`

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$characters = range(1, 30); // Generate Random Data
$others = array_chunk($characters, 8); //Break Them apart
$last = array_pop($others); //Get last row

foreach ( $others as $characters ) {
    echo implode("\t", $characters), PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($last); // Do anything you want with last row
```

Output

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```

Last Row

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 28
    [4] => 29
    [5] => 30
)
```